# How to send RSA private key via POST request

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

I'm engaged in web-app testing. This application has 4 `type="file"` input fields and `input type="text"` field for new file name. If to fill all fields and click "Create" button, application generates new `.bin` file that contains all 4 uploaded file's bodies (configuration `.xml`, certificate `.csr`, binary `.elf` and private key `.pem`).

I used `python-requests` to automate new file generation process:

```
files = {"file1": open("C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file1.xml", 'r'),
         "file2": open("C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file2.crt", 'r'),
         "file3": open("C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file3.pem", 'rb'),
         "file4": open("C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file4.elf", 'rb')}
url = "http://web_app_url.com"
r = requests.post(url, data={"targetName": "File_name"}, files=files)
```

but if to open `File_name.bin` files generated manually (correct file) and via `POST-request` (incorrect file) with `Notepad`, I can see that they have different private key's body part. This parts appears encoded in both cases and looks quite weird, something like that:

```
���dE��}j''�S��Z�Qas$�8��?\��_U�niUT�~}F���S�K���uѻ
���dE��}j''�S��Z�Qas$�8��?\��_U�niUT�~}F���S�K���uѻ
�O�tuփ��f�Ke0!����NY��(�l�@q�E}��>[�AiKgD֗ʛ����@���~JF��H�
```

but the difference is still easily distinguishable

So is there any specific conditions of sending private keys via `POST` that I didn't consider? Should I specify some headers?

P.S. I guess it's quite uncommon issue, but hope that someone have already faced similar problem.. Please let me know if any additional information required

Comment: don't use notepad to view binary data. it can/will pick the wrong character encoding and trash the view. use a proper hex editor.

Comment: @MarcB, Thank you. I'll keep it in mind... But it doesn't matter regarding this issue as even with `�` characters file private key's parts appears totally different

Comment: yes, it does. if notepad decides on the wrong char encoding, then SOME of those bytes in the binary garbage will be valid multi-byte character sequences, and some will be invalid. e.g. in encoding 'x', sequence 0x01 0x02 0x03 might be "letter A with fluffy hair emoji on top" or whatever, while in encoding 'y', the same 3 byte sequence is "Ax" or something. you can't use notepad to visually compare binary files, because it MAY have completely mis-interpreted the byte sequences.

Comment: @MarcB, ok. I got it. I checked files with `HxD` tool to be sure... Byte sequences different for two binary files

Comment: well, rather than stuffing everything together and then comparing that "stuffed" file, start looking at the individual files as they arrive at the server, and make sure the "originals" on the sever are identical to what you've uploaded.